# android content provider gives Unknown URL content://com

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am trying to create a custom content provider and I get a error message

Unknown URL content://com.example.test.samplecontentprovider/yay

I have the following info in my manifest and content provider

```
  <provider
    android:authorities="com.example.test.samplecontentprovider"
    android:multiprocess="true"
    android:name="com.example.test.SampleContentProvider"></provider>

AUTHORITY = "com.example.test.samplecontentprovider"
```

where could I be wrong, please suggest.

I am also including the source code package here.
http://www.fileserve.com/file/p4eNVgK

Comment: change android:name to .SampleContentProvider

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6152713/my-android-contentprovider-cant-find-contentresolver/6153147#6153147

Comment: Tried that already, but I still get the same error

Comment: did you override `public String getType(Uri uri)` in provider?

Comment: where are you getting error message ... could you provide some code ?

Comment: yes I did, but the compiler does not seem to even reach there, because I have a different error thrown up there

Comment: http://www.fileserve.com/file/p4eNVgK, I have zipped and uploaded a project in the fileserve link. It is very small just 54 kb

Comment: @Selvin let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1728/discussion-between-ramji-and-selvin)

Comment: Please join the chat link, so we can chat there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

here you go project fixin'

http://esilo.pl/Yea.zip

few things ...
 Renaud answer ... but there are more errors:

```
// there is no such constructor ... Android looking for simple SampleContentProvider()
//public SampleContentProvider(Context context){
//  mContext=context;
//}

@Override
public boolean onCreate() {
    //so we move mContext initialization here
    mContext = getContext();
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(mContext);
    return true;
}
```

next:

```
public static final class ContentProviderHelper  {
    private ContentProviderHelper() {}
    //private static final String BASE_PATH = "yay"; we don't need it
    public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY); //you dont need it + "/" + BASE_PATH);
    public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE = ContentResolver.CURSOR_ITEM_BASE_TYPE + 
                                                        "/vnd." + COMPANY_NAME + "." + TABLE_NAME;//yay it's stupid :P BASE_PATH;
    public static final String CONTENT_TYPE =   ContentResolver.CURSOR_DIR_BASE_TYPE + 
                                                    "/vnd." + COMPANY_NAME + "." + TABLE_NAME;//yay it's stupid :P BASE_PATH;
    public static final String ID = "_id";
    public static final String TITLE = "title";
    public static final String TEXT = "text";
}
```

next in test.java:

```
    Uri uri = getContentResolver().insert(
            // we should replace SampleContentProvider.ContentProviderHelper.CONTENT_URI with CONTENT_URI + TABLE_NAME
            Uri.withAppendedPath(SampleContentProvider.ContentProviderHelper.CONTENT_URI, SampleContentProvider.TABLE_NAME), values);
```

Answer (score 12):

From the sources provided, you have made a mistake in defining your provider in AndroidManifest.xml: you need to define your provider **within your application tag**, i.e.

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".test"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
        <provider
        android:authorities="com.example.test.samplecontentprovider"
        android:multiprocess="true"
        android:name="com.example.test.SampleContentProvider"></provider>
</application>
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to find any resolve about this, and i rewrite provider tag on my android manifest like this :

```
<provider
    android:name=".database.FVProv"
    android:authorities="com.cevin.sukafilm4"
    android:exported="true"
    android:readPermission="com.cevin.sukafilm4.READ_DATABASE"
    android:writePermission="com.cevin.sukafilm4.WRITE_DATABASE" />
```

Hope it will help you